# Stretch 4 elements equally inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have div which has a width of 100%. Inside of it I have 4 images. How can I stretch the images such that they are all of equal width, such that no spaces exist between the window or the images.

A table row with four cells each styled with `width:100%;` seems like the easy solution. But I know that I'll get screamed at for even suggesting that. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this a valid use of a table? Is there a better alternative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098845/is-this-a-valid-use-of-a-table-is-there-a-better-alternative)

Answer (score 2):

well if the width of your div is 100%, and you have four divs, that need to share that space equally, than you divide 100 by 4, which gives you 25. So set their width to 25%. Also make sure to strip any borders/margins off. That would mess things up.

```
.myDivs{
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  float: left; // Forces divs to flow left to right as opposed to down.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the width like this way

```
<div style="width:100%;height:300px;padding:0;">
    <img src="path" width="25%;padding:0;margin:0;"/>
    <img src="path" width="25%;padding:0;margin:0;"/>
    <img src="path" width="25%;padding:0;margin:0;"/>
    <img src="path" width="25%;padding:0;margin:0;"/>
</div>
```

as the div have width the  will be consider the 25% width of