# Is this a valid use of a table? Is there a better alternative?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a few pages on a site where I need to allow the user to select a color from a list of colors. The list is loaded from a database and can have any number of colors in it. The exact size of the control depends on the page. I know there are great plug ins available to select colors but I built this based on a design. (Read: I can't use third party controls)

I wrote a working solution using a table here (http://jsfiddle.net/Cfj4T/1/). Main purpose in this example is to show that I can change the width of the entire color select by just setting a width on the container:

```
div.select-large {
    width: 560px;
}

div.select-small {
    width: 280px;
}
```

**The question is:** Is this a wrong use of a table? Is there a solution that would use css on the "a" tags or div elements instead? What would that look like?

*Note* - The example was generated by angular and copied into JSFiddle so don't read too much into the extra attributes in the "a" tags.

**All Options In One Place:** - In case anyone wants to see the answers so far I have put them all into the original JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Cfj4T/6/). They work really well, so thanks to all!

Comment: This primarily opinion-based *and* lacks a sufficient description of the issue in the question itself (no HTML given, etc.).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I sincerely am interested in improving the quality of my questions. That said, the core question of what to replace a table with is not an opinion, though there are multiple options. As far as code goes - I provided a JSFiddle which is (IMHO) a little easier than overwhelming the reader with code. Do you have suggestions for what I should have included as far as code or other methods of improving the quality of this/future questions I may have?

Comment: You can see from the answers that this is opinion-based: very strong opinions, with little or no actual evidence to support them on technical grounds.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Last reply: Even assuming everything you say is correct -- I am still interested in the voice of the community. So where do questions like this belong? Is there another stack site that is more appropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `<table>` for anything other than tabular data.

The reason is that now you can get all of the benefits of table-style layout with modern CSS, and your document will be semantically correct which is nice for tools such as screen-readers.

Replace your tables and table cells with elements that use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` and you'll get the same result with nicer markup.

Here's a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/r9AgB/1/

If you have to support older browsers that don't work with `display: table-cell`, set a percentage width on the `<a>` elements depending on the number required. CSS supports decimal percentage values (1.234%).

Comment: Noting that I'm not a designer, is "table-cell" layout frowned on like tables are?

Comment: No, table-style layout is very useful. It's just using `<table>` markup which is incorrect. The various `display: table` values were added to CSS because people would use tables in their HTML merely to get their layout style. It's the best of both worlds :)

Comment: Absolute last question - why is the "width" required in the css on the "a"?

Comment: @drew_w You'll still find the occasional person who has a knee-jerk reaction to using table/table-row/table-cell display properties, but all they're just names that describe the behavior.

Comment: The width is only required since your `<a>` tags have zero content. With zero content and no set width in this method, they simply won't appear. If they had anything else, such as a border, padding, or a bit of text inside,  that would fix it also.

Comment: I was working on an answer based on `display: table-cell` as well, but I guess I was too slow. [Here it is anyway](http://jsfiddle.net/andrelaszlo/4C2kG/).

Comment: +1 @AndréLaszlo for `table-layout: fixed;` which is a better way to avoid the width in my fiddle. Also for the animation ;)

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely not. This is a classic case of "using tables for layout", which is typically a sign of ignorance of better means - not that that's a bad thing, just means you have things to learn ;)

Use `<span>` (or `<a>`) with `display:inline-block` instead. Apply a percentage width to these elements so you can continue to adjust the width of the container dynamically (percentage should be `(100 / number_of_spans)` which can be calculated easily enough)

Comment: Could you *explain* why not, so this becomes an answer for all "can I use a table" questions?

Comment: Edited answer - is that okay?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I have an array loaded from the database via angular. Are you saying that computing the width of an element in a directive is more clear (and better) than a table? NOTE: I'm not a front end developer so I'm really seeking honest feedback here!

Comment: `<table>` carries with it a specific meaning: that you are presenting tabular data (that is, something you might find in an Excel spreadsheet, for example). Using it for layout is abusing the meaning of the element. One thing that a lot of developers need to learn is that *your job is hard!* Personally, I spent hours putting myself through hell just to optimise 4Kb from page requests, but the feedback I've gotten from my users since proves it was worth it!